# AWS Elasticache -- How to flush node from console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elasticache

I have a number of Elasticache nodes running and would like to clear them.  I know it's possible to do this programmatically but I'd like to use the AWS console instead.

How can I flush an Elasticache node using only the AWS console?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only way as i see it will be to reboot the node

Comment: This shouldn't be the answer to this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45780532/3332312 is the right answer.

Comment: I just rebooted my Redis Elasticache node, and the cache maintained through reboot.  Only thing that worked for me using redis-cli and FLUSHALL, from answer below.

Comment: This only work if the node is the primary node.

Answer (score 55):

Connect to your redis-cli with

```
redis-cli -h host -p port_number
```

After you connect, `FLUSHALL`

Comment: this should be the right answer rebooting the nodes is not right

Comment: The op said 'use the AWS console instead'. This can not be done in AWS console. It requires setting up a jumpbox ec2 instance.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to run from the AWS Console, but you can clear the cache running FLUSHALL connecting using telnet:

`telnet HOST PORT`

After you connect, run FLUSHALL.

```
telnet host123.0001.use1.cache.amazonaws.com 6379
Trying 172.0.1.1...
Connected to host123.0001.use1.cache.amazonaws.com.
The escape character is '^]'.
FLUSHALL
+OK
```